# Why is $\sigma \in S_n$ acting covariantly on $n$-covector?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, differential-forms

This is from Tu's book in smooth manifold. Let $V$ be a vector space, and let us define $S_n$ acting on $\Lambda^n(V^*)$ as follows:

> For $\sigma \in S_n$ and $f \in \Lambda^n(V^*)$, $\sigma f(v_1, \cdots, v_n) =  f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(n)})$.

Then, there is a lemma:

> Lemma: For $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$, $\tau(\sigma f) = (\tau\sigma)f$.

> Proof: For $v_1, \cdots, v_n \in V$,
> \begin{align*}
>   \tau(\sigma f) (v_1, \cdots, v_k) &= (\sigma f)(v_{\tau(1)}, \cdots, v_{\tau(k)}) \\
> &= (\sigma f)(w_1, \cdots, w_k) \quad \quad \text{by letting $w_i = v_{\tau(i)})$} \\
> &= f(w_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, w_{\sigma(k)}) \\
> &= f(v_{\tau(\sigma(1))}, \cdots, v_{\tau(\sigma(n))}) = f(v_{\tau\sigma(1)}, \cdots, v_{\tau\sigma(n)}) \\
> &= (\tau\sigma) f(v_1, \cdots, v_k).
> \end{align*}

The proof is perfectly understandable. However, when I tried to apply the theorem holds for specific case, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Say $n = 4$ and $\tau = (12)(34)$ and $\sigma = (23)$. Then, $\tau[1,2,3,4] = [2,1,4,3]$ and $\sigma[1,2,3,4] = [1,3,2,4]$. Also, $\tau\sigma[1,2,3,4] = [3,1,4,2]$. Hence, $(\tau\sigma)f(v_1, \cdots, v_4) = f(v_3, v_1, v_4, v_2)$.

If I define $(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4) = (v_{\tau(1)}, \cdots, v_{\tau(4)})$, then $(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4) = (v_2, v_1, v_4, v_3)$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\tau(\sigma f)(v_1, \cdots, v_4) &= (\sigma f)(v_{\tau(1)}, \cdots, v_{\tau(4)}) \\
&= (\sigma f)(w_1, \cdots, w_4) \\
&= f (w_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, w_{\sigma(4)}) \\
&= f (w_1, w_3, w_2, w_4) \\
&= f (v_2, v_4, v_1, v_3)
\end{align*}

This is not the same result as $f(v_3, v_1, v_4, v_2)$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See Examples 2.5, 2.7, and 2.8 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf. I suspect comparing those to your confusion will be helpful.

Comment: Are you composing in the wrong order?

Comment: @randall essentially yes. But I don't understand why I am composing in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is the claim that $\tau\sigma[1,2,3,4]=[3,1,4,2]$. That composition works like this:
\begin{align*}
\tau\sigma(1) &= \tau(\sigma(1)) = \tau(1)=2;\\
\tau\sigma(2) &= \tau(\sigma(2)) = \tau(3)=4;\\
\tau\sigma(3) &= \tau(\sigma(3)) = \tau(2)=1;\\
\tau\sigma(4) &= \tau(\sigma(4)) = \tau(4)=3.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\tau\sigma[1,2,3,4] = [2,4,1,3]$, and there's no contradiction.

Here's a systematic way to think about these operations. Let $V$ be a vector space. An element of $V^k$ is an ordered $k$-tuple, which is actually a function from $\{1,\dots,k\}$ to $V$. On the other hand, a $k$-form $f$ is a function from $V^k$ to $\mathbb R$.

If $v = (v_1,\dots,v_k) \in  V^k$ and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\dots,k\}$, then the $k$-tuple $(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)})$ is actually the composition $v \circ σ: \{1,\dots,k\} \to V$.  Therefore, by definition, $σf$ is the map from $V^k$ to $\mathbb R$ given by
$$
  \sigma f(v) = f (v \circ \sigma).
$$
It follows that
$$
  \sigma\tau f (v) = f (v \circ \sigma\circ\tau) = \tau f(v \circ \sigma) = \sigma(\tau f)(v).
$$
Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Thank you, Dr. Lee. Meanwhile, I was trying to prove an exercise 5.23 in your textbook on Riemannian Geometry. It asks that Holonomy group based at $p$ is a subgroup of the set of all isometries of $T_p M$. This is my trial so far, but I am completely lost where to go. Could you please comment how I should proceed further? https://www.overleaf.com/read/gnfccsxxydgc

Comment: I am assuming that since I am taking a parallel transport, isometry will be naturally induced. I tried to prove it "hard" way using local coordinate, but it doesn't seem to go in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at Proposition 5.5(f).

Comment: Thank you very much.